# Simulate ajax-request on facebook using python

Tags: python, ajax, facebook

I'm writing a script that login to  facebook to automate things like status updates etc. (I'm aware of fbcmd and co. but want to try it myself). In this case I'm really lost with the ajax stuff facebook uses. For example, if I login on the page and klick on "Find friend" I only see like 10 people. If I scroll down an ajax request is send and I see 10 more persons.
How could I achieve this behavior using a (python) script? I know this question is more a theoretical question and I don't show code, nevertheless I hope you can help me by pointing me in the correct direction.

TIA

Comment: Why not just use the actual API?

Comment: Quote: `I'm aware of fbcmd and co. but want to try it myself` So the answer to your question would be: Because I want to learn sth and understand how it is working.

Comment: Facebook has anti spam/malware/hacking protections that will make it difficult to automate faking user-generated interactions with the site  - if you're only starting to learn how to crawl websites i'd suggest starting with another site before trying to automate Facebook